# Preg_replace with regex and forward slash

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Here is the code:

```
$string = "/My-Item-Here-p/sb-p36abbg.htm";
$str = preg_replace('/^.*-p\s*/', '', $string);
$str = substr($str, 1);
echo $str;
```

This spits out `6abbg.htm`, I would like to have it to only remove everything before and including the "-p/" (note with forward slash).

So I would like it to spit out `sb-p36abbg.htm`

Comment: Is preg_replace a must? Or are you open to other options?

Comment: Then add it. And escape if you wan't to keep your delimiters.

Comment: All you need is `echo basename($string);`

Comment: What if there are 2 or more instances of `-p/` in the source string? Do you want to keep the smallest or the bigger substring?

Comment: there will always only be one instance of `-p/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex: `/^.*-p\/(.*)$/`

```
<?php
$sourcestring="/My-Item-Here-p/sb-p36abbg.htm";
echo preg_replace('/^.*-p\/(.*)$/','\1',$sourcestring);
?>
```

[Codepad link.](http://codepad.org/VPKHa3qz)

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason for you to use regex in that specific case. Just use [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

```
$string = "/My-Item-Here-p/sb-p36abbg.htm";
$str = substr($string, strpos($string, '-p/') + 3);
echo $str;
```

Take into account that using regular expressions where they aren't really needed is a waste of computation resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "/My-Item-Here-p/sb-p36abbg.htm";
$str = preg_replace('/^.*?(?=-p\/)', '', $string);
```